# MVC Razor form button not calling controller specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So within my view, I have:

```
<div id="createProductModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Create Product</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createProductForm", @class = "form-horizontal"}))
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Product.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Product.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Product.IsActive, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Product.IsActive, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="$('#createProductForm').submit();">Add product</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in my `ProductsController` I have added an action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
   return View();
}
```

But for some reason when clicking submit it redirects me to this URL:

```
http://localhost/Product/Create
```

And throws a 404 error like so:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

I've not defined a route within the route configs surely this shouldn't matter?

Does anyone understand what i seem to be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Second parameter of `Html.BeginForm` is the controller name. Given that you have a `ProductsController`, instead of

```
Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", ...
```

Try

```
Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products"
```

Check [FormExtensions.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. This raises another question, is my naming convention for the controller correct? I.e should it be called ProductController and not ProductsController? The page is to display a collection of product's hence the 's'

Comment: @KTOV check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460060/asp-net-mvc-controller-naming-pluralization